# see what files are in Frame Cache

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i am having many plist, in my game-for each level.
i am using this to unload the previous frameCache ,

```
for(int i=1;i<stage;i++)
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFramesFromFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"candys%i.plist",i]];
```

but after a while it seems that the game becomes a little bit slower.

1. i am also loading in real time, the images like this :

> ```
> sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"candy%i.png",1]];
> ```

where `candy1` is a sprite in a spritesheet on the cache and is being loaded
in REAL time- which mean many times a second.
can it be bad ? is it loads the memory to get the sprite from the spriteSheet many times a second ? do i have to pre define it ?

many thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to load/unload individual sprite frames. A sprite frame references a texture. Usually this will be a texture atlas which many different sprite frames use. The sprite frame itself is maybe 16 Bytes of data. The texture may be up to 16 Megabytes.

So unless you remove the entire texture atlas and all the associated sprite frames, all you'll be getting is reduced performance because you're frequently deallocating and loading sprite frames. If you do that multiple times per second you're wasting a lot of time just to load/unload sprite frames.

Rule of thumb: load your entire scene up front, keep everything in memory until scene ends. Only if the entire scene doesn't fit into memory at once should you consider unloading/reloading of objects and data.